# x264 on my Mac keeps giving me "command not found" error

Tags: x264

I just installed x264 via Homebrew on my Mac running MacOS 11.4 Big Sur. I'm trying to encode a video but I can't get x264 to run properly.

This is the command I am running in the Terminal:

`x264 --bitrate 25000 --preset veryslow --bluray-compat --tune film --vbv-maxrate 40000 --vbv-bufsize 30000 --level 4.1 --keyint 30 --open-gop --slices 4 --fake-interlaced --colorprim "bt709" --transfer "bt709" --colormatrix "bt709" --sar 1:1 --pass 1 -o out.264 in.mp4`

and this is what it outputs:

`bash: x264 --bitrate 25000 --preset veryslow: command not found`

If I delete the `--preset` part then it just gets hung up on some other part, like `--tune`.

I have tried `brew doctor` and there are no errors.

If I just run `x264` then it gives me `x264 [error]: No input file. Run x264 --help for a list of options.` so it seems as if x264 is installed. I don't know where to begin troubleshooting this but I'd like to get it to work.

If I simplify the command way down to `x264 -o out.264 in.mp4` then I get:

```
avs [error]: failed to load avisynth
raw [error]: raw input requires a resolution.
x264 [error]: could not open input file `in.mp4' via any method!
```

I would greatly appreciate some pointers on how to get this working.